# In cocos2D, how to display different 'spell' button sprites depending on spell selected in 'equip' scene

Tags: button, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

This is my first post, having spent the last few months benefiting from other peoples questions and answers, so first off a general thanks to stackoverflow and all contributors!!

To my question - in my main game scene I want to have spell buttons which, if selected, call a particular method. Simple enough.

My difficulty is that there are different spells available to the user that they select beforehand in the 'equip' scene, and I need the spell buttons to show different sprites depending on which spell is selected beforehand. Thus, if spells 1 & 2 are selected, then the gameplay scene shows sprites for scenes 1 & 2 in the game scene; whereas if spells 3 & 4 are selected, etc, show sprites for spells 3 & 4.

My difficulty so far has been selecting the sprite to include in the menu buttons depending on the selected abilities.

I haven't posted any code yet because I'm relatively confident with the coding itself, it's just trying to work out how to structure the code to work this out.

For information: the equip scene will save variables to a save-file, that the gameplaylayer will then load the variables from the save file to determine which sprites to show.

Thanks in advance to all - and if I'm breaking any rules or etiquette, or not including the right info, please let me know and I'll amend ASAP!

Thanks again!
Cheeseburger

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Use an object singleton (e.g. GameState singleton) which survives the scene transition to store the spells
2. Use NSUserDefaults to store the spells and load them back after you transition scenes

The link below shows you how to do this:

http://www.karnakgames.com/wp/2010/12/basic-game-data-and-state-persistence-with-nsuserdefaults/